# git ahead by X commits...can't find solution

Tags: git, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

Here's the sequence

I have no edits on the branch at this point

1. I did a `git pull --rebase` in a branch that is tracked to a remote branch
2. Conflicts occured
3. I did `git reset --hard`
4. then `git rebase --abort`

And now it says that my branch is ahead by X commits

I tried doing `git reset --hard` again then `git fetch` then `git fetch origin` then git checkout the branch again all to no avail

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Impossible to answer as we don't know to what commits did you reset your branch and some other important things.

Comment: Try git diff origin/master to see which commits are ahead

Comment: It's `log`, not `diff`

Comment: `git reflog` may help you finding your `HEAD`

Comment: @pillarOfLight: "branch is ahead by X commits" simply means that you have X commits which arent pushed to the tracked branch yet. If you undid the pull and havent pushed since, that's only logical. You'll have to pull and/or merge into the upstream changes and push it to the tracked branch for that message to go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are `X commits ahead` is a consequence of the implied `git fetch` that was done during your initial `git pull` (you also did an explicit `git fetch` afterwards). It just means that these commits aren't pushed to the tracked branch yet. That's not a problem at all. This message will disappear once those commits are pushed.